# Run-time error '3075': "syntax error (missing operator) in certain query expressions"

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub cmdSendOrder_Click()
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO OrderSummary(OrderNumber, SupplierCode, DateOrdered, EmployeeNumber) " & _
          " VALUES (" & Me.txtOrderNumber & "','" & Me.cboSupplierCodeO & "','" & Me.txtDateO & "','" & Me.txtEmployeeO & "') "
    'refresh data on list of form
    OrderSummarySub.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

My code gets a run-time error saying it has a syntax error (missing operator) in certain query expressions. I'm pretty sure the names I put above were correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your first single quote before Me.txtOrderNumber:

```
"INSERT INTO OrderSummary(...) VALUES ('" & ...
```